# Is it possible to setText for an Edittext for a long data type element in android

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea, long-integer

Is it possible to setText for an Edittext view for a long data type element in android XML? I know that setText can take integer but it is not accepting any long data type. So how can I write a long variable in an Edittext without converting it to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not you make it to String first:

```
yourEditText.setText(String.valueOf(yourLongVariable));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
editText.setText(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable((String.valueOf(yourLongValue))));
```

You can't set String value to EditText so convert the String value to Editable as well.

Answer (score 0):

`setText` with `int` type parameter exist to put string resource into `TextView`. If you put just a some random in you will have an exception that will say to you that string with such id doesn't exist. To put number by `setText` method you have to convert it to string as [Levan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62134565/5422725) mentioned.